# Data retrieved from database ignoring line breaks

Tags: php, mysql, html

Data that is stored in my mysql database, has the breaks of text input properly, but when retrieved the data no longer has the breaks, and everything is displayed as one string without any `<br>`.  Any idea why this would occur?

The data column is the format `text`,
for example: in a table there is:

```
hey
how
do
you
do
```

After retrieving the data ill  `echo $mesarray[0][message];` and the result is:

```
hey how do you do
```

I want the line breaks to appear, but they dont.

Comment: do you mean `\n` or `<br />` you mention both, dose the source have the expected string, outputting to the browser would make the string look like there are no "breaks" perhaps your looking to use the nl2br() function.

Comment: yes that seems to be it, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is because HTML does not understand line breaks. They need `<br />` tags to break lines.

There is a function called [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) which can be used to convert new lines to `<br>`

```
echo nl2br($mesarray[0][message]);
```